# equality between lists and conversion of char into int within a list

Tags: c, list, equality, converters

```
// Igualdade entre listas --> Teste 1 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define BTT 10 


void create_pirolito(int list[BTT]);
void create_retardado(int list[BTT]);
void compare_lists(int list1[BTT], int list2[BTT]);
void prints_both(int list1[BTT], int list2[BTT]);



void create_pirolito(int list[BTT])
{
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        list[i]=rand()%10;
    }
}



void create_retardado(int list[BTT])
{
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
         list[i]=rand()%20;
    }
}



void prints_both(int list1[BTT], int list2[BTT])
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(int z=0; z<BTT; z++)
    {
      printf("(%2d  %2d)\n", list1[i], list2[j]);
      i++;
      j++;
    }
}



void compare_lists(int list1[BTT], int list2[BTT])
{
    char x='X';
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<BTT; j++)
        {
            if(list1[i]==list2[j])
            {
                list1[i]==(int)(x);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}




int main()
{
    int pirolito[BTT];
    int retardado[BTT];
    
    create_pirolito(pirolito);
    create_retardado(retardado);
    compare_lists(pirolito, retardado);
    prints_both(pirolito, retardado);
    
    return 0;
}
```

My intention is to compare two different lists and whenever there are equalities, the number saved in that index is exchanged for the letter 'X', this only in the pirolito list, but when I compile there is no error only a large space and then follow the printing of the two lists but without the character 'X' in the respective equalities.

Comment: The large space comes from the `compare_lists` `printf("\n")`.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to declare `char x` and then cast it to `int` when you use it.  `'X'` is an int, and it seems cleaner to avoid the cast and just do `int x = 'X';`.  Not a big deal, but it's convenient to remember that `'X'` is an `int`, since it is a common error to do things like `char c = getchar()` (`getchar` returns an int, and assigning it to a char makes it impossible to distinguish between EOF and valid data).  It's best to burn it into your brain that `'X'` is an `int`.  (Note that this is  different in C++)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the datatype `char` is just a single-byte integer. The ASCII character 'X' is represented by the decimal 88. It is not "a character", just a different interpretation of an underlying binary (think decimal if you are not familiar) value.

In `compare_lists`, when an equality is found, you are just assigning your list the value 88 at that position. When you are printing the list, you use `%d` as the print format, which means that the value is printed as an integer. If you used `%c`, the value 88 would be printed as the ASCII character 'X' and all other values in the list would be printed as ASCII characters (though not the ones you probably think).

You cannot do what you want without imposing some restriction on the allowed values in the list, for the simple reason that 88 could exist in the list before the `compare_lists` call, or it could be written during it.

If you insist on your current approach, you would need to restrict the values of your list to **not** contain some chosen numbers. For example, arbitrarily say that `-3` is not a legal value in your list. Then, in `compare_lists`, you write `-3` wherever the conditions are met and in your `prints_both` you need to check if `list1[i]` is equal to `-3`, in which case you could use `printf("(X %2d)\n", list2[i])`, otherwise use your old `printf` statement